# android.intent.action.MAIN ERROR while launching on device

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-launcher, launching

I'm trying to run this android app on my device but it keeps show this error and I did not find solution for it

> $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.seniorproject/com.example.seniorproject.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

here is Manifests file

> 

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SeniorProject">
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:exported="false"
         />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false"
         />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
         />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```